# Local Computer Address Show in Client App Error

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to know why this my computer address is showing in client computer application error.

[image]

why this one is happening, I have no idea.

Comment: Sounds like you send your local build to a client... that's seem to be a problem - you should not be sending clients bits compiled on your local computer - you should be using some build system... (Or you are asking why debugging information include file path to allow debugging code?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information comes from .PDB file which contains debug information, and it were generated during the compilation.

You might consider send your release code not debug code to your customer, which will remove the .PDB file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Recommendation not to *generate* PDB is simply bad idea as you will use strong words about person who did that when you try to debug client's problems or minidumps... But indeed you should not be *sending* PDB out to customers...

Comment: Thanks, I will test with this and this one should be answered.